# Set permission for each page user wise in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, permissions, sql-server-2012-express

I am working with a very large application in ASP.NET and SQL Server 2012 Express.

Mainly there are few folders as roles like `Admin, Manager, Accountant` etc.

In those folders there are hundreds of `.aspx` pages.

I also have a custom user management system with roles like Admin, Manager, Accountant.

I am looking for a permission mechanism with which I will be able to set permission for each page with each user. And I need permission like READ, EDIT, DELETE for each page and each user.

When user logs in, and clicks on page link, if he has permission to see that page, he will get the page otherwise not.

Is there any framework or code or something like that I can utilize?
Or can somebody give me idea on how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a `web.config` in each folder. In your config file you can set the role based permission like below for each specific folder

```
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow roles="Admin"/>
    <deny users="?"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Comment: I know about folders, but I want permissions set for each page.